# Put longest field in dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with three columns, all are text. How can I create a new column that only contains the text from the longest of the three columns? I'm defining the length as a simple character count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm really not sure how efficient this is, but, you can use `.applymap(len)` to everything in the DF - take the maximum index on the columns axis and then use `.lookup(...)` on it, eg:

Starting with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     'a': ['a', 'bb', 'c'], 
     'b': ['aaa', 'bb', 'cc'], 
     'c': ['a', 'bbb', 'ccc'] 
})
```

You can do:

```
mx = df.applymap(len).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Which gives you the relevant column to take from each row:

```
0    b
1    c
2    c
dtype: object
```

Then you look those up in the original DF and assign back to the DF as a new column, eg:

```
df['d'] = df.lookup(mx.index, mx.values)
```

Gives you a final DF of:

```
    a    b    c    d
0   a  aaa    a  aaa
1  bb   bb  bbb  bbb
2   c   cc  ccc  ccc
```

Comment: If speed doesn't matter, another option would be `df.apply(max, key=len, axis=1)` (gasp, apply, I know).

Comment: @coldspeed given what `.lookup` does - I wouldn't be surprised were that a better answer :) (it was originally what I was thinking but thought I'd try to stick more to pandas stuff... but yes, I'm not 100% happy with this answer - feel free to go for it!)

Answer (score 3):

Using data from [@JonClement's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55698209/4909087). . . Another option would be a row-wise application of python's `max` function:

```
df
    a    b    c
0   a  aaa    a
1  bb   bb  bbb
2   c   cc  ccc

df['d'] = df.apply(max, key=len, axis=1)
df

    a    b    c    d
0   a  aaa    a  aaa
1  bb   bb  bbb  bbb
2   c   cc  ccc  ccc
```

Answer (score 2):

One way `argmax` with `numpy` `vectorize`

```
df.columns[np.vectorize(len)(df.values).argmax(1)]
Out[574]: Index(['b', 'c', 'c'], dtype='object')

df.values[np.arange(len(df)),np.vectorize(len)(df.values).argmax(1)]
Out[575]: array(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: @coldspeed I feel like using values may a little bit speed up the whole process, not sure about the timing .